# Can't see reputation

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page

[In my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4161269/anik-islam-abhi?tab=topactivity), I can't see the reputation in the box below:

[image]

Is it a bug or is it just in my browser?

Comment: I don't see it either http://stackoverflow.com/users/4161269/anik-islam-abhi?tab=topactivity

Comment: Wow, it's more weird in [the **reputation** tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4161269/anik-islam-abhi?tab=reputation)...Shouldn't *2 upvotes + 1 downvote == 18 rep* ? [Image here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/aykm3.png).

Comment: ^ Oh, possible the system means `+20/-2` instead of `+2/-2`. But maybe he's drunk, and forgot type a `0`.

Comment: @Kevin Have you never heard about "reputation cap"? The upvotes minus downvotes per day are capped at 200.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You hit the reputation cap, which means you can only earn up to 200 reputation in one day from certain events. This can cause blank values in some places as you stop receiving reputation from upvotes. In this particular case, it's because you got a downvote, losing 2 reputation, and then got an upvote which regained you that 2 reputation on the same post. The net reputation change is 0, so there is nothing to display for that post. You can see what really happened by viewing the post in your reputation history, which lists it as +2 / -2.

Comment: Shouldn't it display 0 instead of blank ?

Comment: Our standard action for all reputation values is to not display anything when it's 0, rather than displaying an actual 0.

Comment: So you are saying that it's not a bug . it's a default behavior of SO ?

Comment: Because, you know... blank is easier to understand than zero.